# How to implement SIWE using web3js

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

Is there a way to implement the client part of SIWE (Sign In With Ethereum) using Web3.js instead of ethers.js?

In SIWE's [example](https://github.com/spruceid/siwe-quickstart/blob/main/01_frontend/src/index.js) they do:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const signature = await signer.signMessage(message)
```

But I can't figure out how to do something similar in my dapp which is build using web3.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ethers.js` [signer.signMessage()](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/signer/#Signer-signMessage) takes a binary message, prepends it with the standardized prefix, and then requests the `signer` to sign the message.

You can achieve the same with `web3js` [eth.sign()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.1/web3-eth.html#sign) method.

```
const signature = await web3.eth.sign(message, signerAddress);
```